# Activated Virtualenv in commands but the bracket is not showing in the directory [Python]

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, zsh

I am trying to learn django. 
In VS code, I have installed pip and virtualenv.

I created a env folder by using virtualenv command.

```
$ virtualenv env
```

To activate virtual environment, I ran the command below.

```
$ source env/bin/activate
```

The result I was expecting to see was I see the little brackets in front of directory address as below:

```
dhkang@dhkang-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S145-15API ~/fastcampus/django
 % (env)
```

However, I do not see any brackets to indicate that the virtual environment is being activated.

```
dhkang@dhkang-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S145-15API ~/fastcampus/django
 % source env/bin/activate
```

However, I do not see (env) here. I don't know if the virtual environment is activated or not.

Does anyone know how to resolve to show the brackets when virtual environment is activated?

Comment: The `(env)` should show *before* the directory, not *after*.  If you still don't see it, I'm not too sure if it's activated properly.  Do a `which pip` or `which python` and see if the path given is the `venv` one.

Comment: Do you have something in your `zsh` configuration that will overwrite whatever changes `env/bin/activate` tries to make to your prompt?

Comment: I ran which pip and which python to check

 **% which pip**
**/home/dhkang/.pyenv/shims/pip**

**% which python**
**/home/dhkang/fastcampus/webcrawiling/venv/bin/python**

Comment: Could you please tell me if I need to make any configuration based on info above? 

Also,, I do not know if my zsh has any configuration to overwrite the changes env/bin/acitavate tries to make to my prompt. I am fairly new to ubuntu and vscode. 

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I resolved the issue by installing oh-my-zsh. There must have been some settings that I didnt know in zsh. I will try to know these settings later. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I resolved my issue.

It was one of zsh settings that I could never imagine as I am fairly new to Linux.

What I did was **trying out other shell types like bash.** I tried bash as default terminal and the bracket indicating it's on virtual environment was showing.

In the end, I have installed oh-my-zsh and changed the theme 'agnoster'. Now, anywhere in terminal or VScode clearly show the brackets. With regards to oh-my-zsh, refer to the link https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you are using builtin `zsh` in vscode, After you activated the `virtualenv` you should delete the terminal and start new one using the view tab...

1. Delete terniaml using icon in right top of the terminal. (Use the trash icon)

[image]

2. Start new terminal..
   `View > Terminal`

Comment: I tried the way you suggested but the brackets are still not showing.. I am still figuring this out.

Comment: I resolved the issue by installing oh-my-zsh. With your answer, I gained the idea. Thanks for your help!!